# Find distinct rows with objects list using JPA and Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have a relation many to many between tags and posts. I need to write jpa query to find all posts by list of tags. I can do it like: findDistinctByTagsIn(List tags) and it works but I need custom query. I have tried

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT p FROM Post p WHERE p.tags IN :tags")
```

but it gives me an error:

```
select distinct post0_.id as id1_0_, post0_.content as content2_0_, post0_.name as name3_0_, post0_.user_id as user_id4_0_ from posts post0_ cross join posts_tags tags1_, tags tag2_ where post0_.id=tags1_.posts_id and tags1_.tags_id=tag2_.id and (. in (? , ?))
```

field in post entity:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
private List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>();
```

field in tag entity:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, mappedBy = "tags")
private List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<>();
```

Someone have idea what is wrong? I tried with join but still can't figure out how to do it

Comment: As any JPQL documentation would tell you, IN is for `{single_value} IN {list_of_values}`, and you aren't doing that. I'd expect the JPA provider to give a damn sight clearer error message than that one though

Answer (score 0):

You can either use @Query with JPQL or @Query with SQL

@***Query with JPQL approach***

public interface ModelJpaRepoaitory extends JpaRepository {

```
@Query(“select m from model m where modelname= :name)
List<Model> findModelsByName(@Param(“name”) String name);
}


@***Query with SQL approach***
public interface ModelJpaRepoaitory extends JpaRepository<Model , Long> {
@Query(“select m from model m where modelname= :name , nativeQuery=true)
List<Model> findModelsByName(@Param(“name”) String name);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to write custom queries, you can use JPA specifications. Here is the link for more information :-

https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-spring-data-specifications

Comment: That is "Spring Data Specifications", not "JPA Specifications". The JPA spec has NOTHING AT ALL called "Specifications"